# fieldset and form HTML

Tags: php, html, fieldset

I got weird problem over here. I was using  in html to send it to my script .php. Everything was fine, script was running like it should. It was looking a little ugly without margins so I tried to edit it a bit. I found a way with some CSS changes and I used . Now it's broken. I don't really know why.

Here's the HTML code:
Before form:

```
[insert_php]
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

[/insert_php]
```

After form

```
 <form action="http://sute.com/rp.php" method="post">
    <fieldset><label for="email">Email:</label><input name="email" size="20" type="text" />
    <label for="user_name">Nick:</label><input name="user_name" size="20" type="text" />
    <label for="server">Server:</label><select name="server">    
    <option value="1">1</option>         
    <option value="2">2</option>         
    <option value="3">3</option></select></fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="reward" value="123">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="[insert_php]echo "$current_user->ID";[/insert_php]">
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></center></form>
```

It was working without label for so I don't know why it's not working now, any idea? I'll also give you PHP code here.

```
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']);
$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$server = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['server']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$nagroda = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reward']);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
echo "<body style='background: url(http://bg.com/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed center center;'>";
echo "<background-repeat: no-repeat;>";

$pkt = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = $user_id AND meta_key='mycred_default'");
if ( $pkt > 0 OR $user_id == 0) {

 $message = 'Sorry, you need more LPoints.';

    echo "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'> //not showing me this
        alert('$message');
        window.location.replace((\"http://sute.com\"));
    </SCRIPT>";
    mysql_close();
}
rest of the code, doesn't really matter because it ends here with my problem.
```

so as I said - it was working before I used fieldsets.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the page your php script is at?
http://sute.com/rp.php

```
<form action="http://sute.com/rp.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="email">Email:</label><input name="email" size="20" type="text" />
        <label for="user_name">Nick:</label><input name="user_name" size="20" type="text" />
        <label for="server">Server:</label>
        <select name="server">    
            <option value="1">1</option>         
            <option value="2">2</option>         
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="reward" value="123"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="[insert_php]echo "$current_user->ID";[/insert_php]">
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></center>
</form>
```

Comment: Weird. Orginaly it was like you said. First closing select then fieldset. I don't know why in my post there is closing fieldset first. Still not working. More ideas? Thanks for trying. I changed it already to make sure noone will think that it's like you said :)

Comment: Nevermind. I was just stupid. I forgot that I set in php $pkt > 0 instead of $pkt < 0.